# Is there an IntelliSense add-in that allows icons/graphics in XML comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

[As proposed](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/blog/2010/06/03/xcode-ui-improvements/) by Brandon Walkin (for Xcode, but same thing), more visualization in the IDE can help productivity. In particular, I'd like to provide little icons to better convey the meaning of enum choices or classes (such as UI controls), roughly like this:

[image]

The built-in XML comment syntax clearly doesn't support this, but maybe someone has written an add-in to add support for, say, a `<img>` tag?

Comment: interesting.. although intellisense could become really heavy.
remember the intellisense cache db issues back in VS08?..

Answer (score 1):

Man I love the Visual Studio Gallery for all the good things it contains.

Never seen anything like what you suggest there, but have seen plugin's for adding that kind of content to comments tho.  This is one that I can find in there now (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e216ec81-730b-4022-8305-25c39eb1f820), but I distinctly  remember that there used to be one that allowed you to link to an image file (an export from say visio or it's ilk), and it would display it inline.  I can't find it now tho :-(

You might want to look at this one, which is close, but not quite on the money http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3eaa4fc-f2de-43ad-92ee-f0f257b79005.  The source code is available here: http://csharpintellisense.codeplex.com/

And I'd actually like to thank you for drawing my attention back to that fabulous repository of goodness.